# Android не может найти класс

Tags: android, unity3d

в `Google Play Console` пишет такой сбой в `ANR ошибках`, не могу понять в чем причина и как это править.

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и решил ее напишите пожалуйста каким образом у вас это удалось.

Эта проблема на 30 устройствах, все они имеют `Android 4.`

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2264)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2390)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:824)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:640)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1061)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2255
```

Comment: У вас стоят какие-то плагины? Возможно они пытаются использовать какой-то фукнционал из более поздних версий. В дебаге не отловить, что именно запрашивает этот класс? Да и у самого Unity минимальная поддерживаемая версия 4.1

Comment: в дебаге не получится потому что у меня нету устройства с android 4. в проекте установлено с 4.1 и выше. Мы убрали все сервисы, а именно их инициализацию, т.е. библиотеки остались, но их ничего не вызывает и не дергает